# Can Raku's introspection list all the multi candidates across different files/Modules?

Tags: documentation, raku, introspection, rakudo

When a proto and multis are defined in the same module, `Type.^lookup('method').candidates` returns a list of all multi candidates.  However, this appears not to work when the proto lives in a different file/module from the multis.

```
say Setty.^lookup('grab').candidates;   # OUTPUT: ()
```

Is there any way to find the full list of multi candidates through Raku's introspection?  Or is there no alternative to grepping through the source code?  (I ask because having a full list of multi candidates applicable to a given proto would be [helpful for documentation purposes](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/3209).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far as `multi` `methods` go, it's not really to do with being in the same module or file at all. Consider these classes:

```
class Base {
    proto method m(|) { * }
    multi method m() { 1 }
}

class Derived is Base {
    multi method m() { 2 }
}
```

Whenever we compose a class that contains multi methods, we need to attach them to a controlling `proto`. In the case of `Base`, this was explicitly written, so there's nothing to do other than to add the `multi` candidate to its candidate list. Had we not written a `proto` explicitly in `Base`, however, then one with an empty candidate list would have been generated for us, with the same end result.

The process I just described is a bit of a simplification of what really happens, however. The steps are:

1. See if this class has a `proto` already; if so, add the `multi` to it
2. Otherwise, see if any base class has a `proto`; if so, clone it (in tern cloning the candidate list) and add the `multi` to that.
3. Otherwise, generate a new `proto`.

And step 2 is really the answer to your question. If we do:

```
say "Base:";
.raku.say for Base.^lookup('m').candidates;

say "Derived:";
.raku.say for Derived.^lookup('m').candidates;
```

Then the output is:

```
Base:
multi method m (Base: *%_) { #`(Method|82762064) ... }
Derived:
multi method m (Base: ) { #`(Method|82762064) ... }
multi method m (Derived: ) { #`(Method|82762208) ... }
```

That is, the candidate list in `Base` has one entry, and the candidate list in `Derived` has the entry cloned from `Base` as well as a new one.

Pretty much everything follows this principle: derived classes reference their base class (and the roles they do), but base classes (and roles) don't know about their descendants.

Comment: «2. Otherwise, see if any base class has a proto; if so, clone it (in tern cloning the candidate list) and add the multi to that.»  So, does the behavior I observed turn on the fact that this step involves a clone rather than a shared reference?  I was imagining that there would be one and only one proto (with multiple classes being able to add candidates to its candidates list).  Now that I've written that out, though, I can see how that would create obvious problems of shared mutable state and (I think?) issues for garbage collection.

Comment: Yes, plus the extra candidates "at a distance" could even potentially affect the sort order and/or introduce new ambiguities, so there'd be semantic problems aside from the GC and concurrency ones.